# Action helper, something like evt.target

Tags: ember.js

Is in ivoked controller method some reference to DOM elem, on which was the {{action}} helper declared?

Or how can I get reference to that DOM elem?

Here is code example.

1. Code in the View, e.g. action on **label** or **button**

   ```
   <div class="view">
       {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="isCompleted" class="toggle"}}
       <label {{action editingA on="doubleClick"}}>{{title}}</label>
       <button class="destroy" {{action deleteAction}}></button>
   </div>
   ```
2. Code in the Controller, as you can see, I'm trying focus some elem after **doubleClick** on the **label**

   ```
   App.TodoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

       isEditing: false,

       editingA: function() {
           this.set('isEditing', true);
           // $(this).focus();
           // How to get reference to label DOM elem
       },

       updateAction: function() {
           var todo = this.get('model');

           this.get('store').commit();

           this.set('isEditing', false);
       }

   });
   ```

Comment: do you have code that you've tried?

Comment: Basically, you can't. A close examination of `action.js` will show that the originating js event never gets exposed to your method that ends up getting called.

Comment: Sry I didn't get any email notify that somebody reply to my question, so I have upgraded my question and added some code example.

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey And how can I solve this or what is the recommanded solution?

Comment: You should encapsulate this behaviour in a custom view. Take a look at App.EditField in https://github.com/emberjs/examples/blob/master/contacts/app.js, noting that it relies on the template defined at the bottom of https://github.com/emberjs/examples/blob/master/contacts/index.html. Keep in mind that the context rules for templates have changed since this code was written, so the template would be different (using `view.` in front of the property paths)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of my question is completly desribed in **[Ember.View](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html)** API documentation, in section named **RESPONDING TO BROWSER EVENTS**.

The custom view should be created, when I need reference to DOM element, where was the {{action}} helper declared. The reference is passed as the first argument to invoked method.

Here is the sample code:

```
AView = Ember.View.extend({
  click: function(event){
    // will be called when when an instance's
    // rendered element is clicked
  }
});
```